# Binatone 845W router disconnects after a few hours

Tags: wireless-router, modem, adsl-router

I have a Binatone 845 Wireless ADSl2+ Router.

It works for 1-2 hours and then gets disconnected. The DSL light doesn't light up, neither do the ethernet/wireless lights. Only the power light is on.

I have a few questions:

1. Can it work without incoming DSL (i.e. as a router only)? I'm not able to get it to work even if I remove the DSL cable.
2. What could be the possible cause of it working only within a specific time period? Is it possible that it's due to lack of power in the DSL line?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Airtel internet connection, they use a dynamic IP address pooling, so whenever the lease time of a IP address expires, the modem is disconnected and a new ip address is assigned .Ask the Airtel technical team to look into the matter.